# Get the SUM of array (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays

I need to calculate numbers from the array.

I have a code written but I don't know how exactly I would need to write that I could get a summation of the numbers in the array.

If You would recommend some good material to learn something like so of, I would be thankful.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int n;
int array_1[20];
const char D[]= "Data.txt";
const char R[]="Rezults.txt";

void to_read ( int &n, int array_1[])
{
ifstream fd(D);
fd>>n;
for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
fd>>array_1[i];
fd.close();
}

int to_sum()
{
int m=0;
for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
m=m+array_1[i];
return m;
}

void to_print(int n, int mas_1[])
{
int sum=0;
ofstream fr(R);
fr<<n<<endl;
for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
fr<<array_1[i]<<" ";
fr<<endl;
sum=to_sum();
fr<<sum<<endl;
fr.close();

}
int main()
{
to_read(n, array_1);
to_sum();
to_print(n, array_1);


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried compiling it yet?  I think you're missing a to_read() function.  Also change the return type for to_sum() from void to int, since you return the sum.  I think you could stand to do a little more reading on your own first.  There's lots of C++ tutorials out there.

Comment: Thanks @Jmc! It was my mistake to write void instead of int near to_sum().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewritten your code, removed global variables, changed formatting for easier reading, rename some variables to more explain for what they are and add function prototypes. Hope this will help you a little.

There are still lot of places which should be changed, but i want to keep as close to your original code as possible.

If you have any questions feel free to ask.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

//functions prototypes (these will be moved to header file if you wanna use this code from another file)
void to_read(int &len, int * array, const char * name); //added name parameter to avoid glogal variables
void to_print(int len, int * array, const char * name);
int to_sum(int len, int * array);                       //added parameters to avoid global variables

int main()
{
    int lenght = 20;                //moved to here, try to avoid global variables
    int array_1[lenght];            //preconfigured size depend on variable
    const char D[] = "Data.txt";
    const char R[] = "Rezults.txt";

    to_read(lenght, array_1, D);
    //to_sum(lenght, array_1);     //not needed here, not storing/processing result
    to_print(lenght, array_1, R);

    return 0;
}

void to_read(int &len, int * array, const char *name)
{
    int lenght;

    ifstream fd(name);              //you should check if opening was successful

    fd >> lenght;                     //you should check if reading was successful
    if (lenght < len) len = lenght; //to prevent overflow of array, read max 20

    for (int i=0; i<len; i++){
        fd >> array[i];
    }

    fd.close();
}

int to_sum(int len, int * array)
{
    int sum=0;

    for (int i=0; i<len; i++){
        sum += array[i];            //changed sum = sum + value; to sum += value; its same but this is more often used
    }

    return sum;
}

void to_print(int len, int * array, const char *name)
{
    int sum = to_sum(len, array);
    ofstream fr(name);

    fr << len << endl;

    for (int i=0; i<len; i++){
        fr << array[i] << " ";
    }

    fr << endl;
    fr << sum << endl;

    fr.close();
}
```

Comment: Hey @Simi! Thanks a lot! I looked at the code and I do not understand two things so far:
   ///   
first - why do we have to use this * sign? I know that & is used before unknown yet variable. But what is * used for? `void to_read(int &len, int * array, const char *name)`   ///   second - Dont we have to use 'D' instead of 'name'?  `ifstream fd(name); `

Comment: * is used for pointer. When you have array, you have pointer to first element in array. That is also reason why we have to send length of array to function as well. We don't know that from just pointer.

Comment: For second question. No we have to use "name", as we declared in function that parameter is named "name". "D" is only known inside main function.

Comment: "I know that & is used before unknown yet variable"  This is wrong, & is used when you pass variable using reference instead value. That means you will get new name for that variable inside of function and when you change value of this variable, it will be changed in outside of function as well. You can do same with pointers (*), but it would have different syntax. When passing variable to function by value. You will get new variable inside of function and that means if you change it, it won't affect original variable.